# CoroutineScope cannot be reused after an exception thrown

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class that implements CoroutineScope, and it has a function `run`, which has one parameter for me to test if I want to throw an exception.
In the example, I found the code block inside the `launch` in the second `run` call is not actually executed. Is this intended behavior? It took me some time to find out the problem in my original code because the log does not say anything until I wrote the sample code to test. If that is intended, what is the best practice to fix the problem? What I want to achieve is to reuse the `run` function, and be able to catch the exception inside that function.

```
package coroutine.exceptions

import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun log(msg: String) = println("$msg (${Thread.currentThread().name})")
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
    log(e.localizedMessage)
}

fun main() = runBlocking {

    val test1 = TestReuseCoroutineAfterException("test1")
    test1.run(true)
    delay(2000)
    test1.run(false)
    delay(2000)

    log("finished")
}


class TestReuseCoroutineAfterException(private val testName: String) :
    CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) {

    fun run(throwException: Boolean) {
        log("$testName: call - started")
        launch(exceptionHandler) {
            if (throwException)
                throw Exception("$testName: call - throw exception")
            else
                log("$testName: call - done")
        }
        log("$testName: call - ended")
    }

}
```

Output:

```
test1: call - started (main)
test1: call - ended (main)
test1: call - throw exception (DefaultDispatcher-worker-1)
test1: call - started (main)
test1: call - ended (main)
finished (main)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 4):

When you create a `CoroutineScope` like this:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
```

It uses `Job()` as its Job, and `Job()` cancels the scope if an exception was throws in child coroutine. If you don't want to cancel the whole scope if a child fails, use [SupervisorJob](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#supervision):

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob())
```

After this change your code prints:

```
test1: call - started (main)
test1: call - ended (main)
test1: call - throw exception (DefaultDispatcher-worker-1)
test1: call - started (main)
test1: call - ended (main)
test1: call - done (DefaultDispatcher-worker-2)
finished (main)
```